# Extend TextField with label

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to write something like this:

```
{{ view MyApp.MyTextField label="Your name" valueBinding="person.fullname" }}
```

and output this: `<div><label>Your name</label><input type="text" /></div>` where the TextField is of course bound to person.fullname. I'm planning to implement some kind of validation in this view later.

How do I do this in Ember?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to create a custom view like so:

```
App.FieldView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: 'field clearfix'.w(),

  defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div>{{view LabelView}}{{view DataView}}</div>'),

  label: '',

  /**
   * Class representing the label tag
   */
  LabelView: Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'label',

    attributeBindings: ['for'],

    'for': '',

    textBinding: 'parentView.label',

    defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{text}}')
  }),

  /**
   * Class representing the data capture control.
   */
  DataView: null,

  /**
   * Set the 'for' attribute for the label to that of the data view
   */
  willInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();

    var childViews = this.get('childViews');
    var labelView = childViews[0];
    var dataView = childViews[1];
    labelView.set('for', dataView.$().attr('id'));
  }

});
```

You can then use it like so for textbox

```
MyApp.MyField= MyApp.FieldView.extend({
  label: 'Label Text',

  DataView : Ember.TextField.extend({
    valueBinding: 'MyApp.pageController.myFieldData'
  })
});
```

or like this for a drop down

```
MyApp.MyField= MyApp.FieldView.extend({
  label: 'Label Text',

  DataView : Ember.Select.extend({
    ...
  })
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow this is awesome!! I had figured out a way which worked okay, but this is just so clean and nice. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: Try creating a `value` property under `MyApp.FieldView` (just like the `label` property) and then bind your data control value to that. Something like `valueBinding: 'parentView.value'`.